# Prototyping the File object

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is it possible to prototype the File object? I currently have the problem that the File object in Firefox 7+ does not have the `fileName` attribute any more, but the `name` attribute.

My code relies extensively on `fileName` and I would like to find an easier way than changing all occurrences.

Comment: have you tried to add it to the prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function(File){

    if( !File ) {
    return;
    }


    function getFileName(){
    return this.name;
    }

 File.prototype.__defineGetter__( "fileName", getFileName );

})(window.File)
```

It should have no effect on browsers that have `fileName` because the prototype is only looked at if it's not found in a `File` instance object itself.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj3B2/2/ (tested in firefox, chrome and opera)

Edited because opera didn't support `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps creating File.prototype.fileName setter and getter, that set/get name, will solve your problem.

However, I do not really know how it does work, and I do not know either if the code below works.

```
if(! ("name" in File.prototype) ){
    File.prototype.fileName = {
      get function(){
        return this.name;
      }, 
      set function(val){
        this.name = val;
      }
    };
}
```